# Is it a good idea to implement middleware design for my non-HTTP business logic?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, middleware

Most of us are now used to HTTP middlewares from recent implementations, starting with node.js ecosystem. We also have some business logic (in a separate business logic library that applications extend) that can be quite layered. This is more like a queue of operations (services in code), that respond to an external message given to this whole component, [FILO](https://techterms.com/definition/filo) style.

Pseudo-code would read something like this:

```
inviteFriendsOperation = createFIFOQueue(message)
inviteFriendsOperation.add(PrepareFriendsList)
inviteFriendsOperation.add(RemoveFamily)
inviteFriendsOperation.add(SendMobilePush { delete successfully pushed friends from message.friendList })
inviteFriendsOperation.add(SendWebPush { delete successfully pushed friends from message.friendList })
inviteFriendsOperation.add(SendEmail { here, message.friendList only contains those who failed for mobile and web push})
updatedMessage = inviteFriendsOperation.run()

print updatedMessage.successfulMobilePushes
print updatedMessage.successfulWebPushes
print updatedMessage.successfulEmails
print updatedMessage.friendList
```

So we would create a queue of objects that execute operations and update `message` that was sent to the queue. It starts running in the order of `add`, reaches `SendEmail` and then runs back to the first operation ending at `PrepareFriendsList`. It finally returns the updated `message` as the result of whole operation.

`message` would have a strongly applied interface, so misunderstandings would be minimalized.

Apart from HTTP middlewares, I haven't seen this pattern applied very often and when I researched, I found results for system architecture patterns, rather than code.

Is this a good method? Can you point me to some examples/papers/articles?

Comment: I don't get why it "*then runs back to the first operation ending at `PrepareFriendsList`*". What do the operations do at that stage?

Answer (score 1):

**'Middleware like'** pattern can be useful in your case. The term **middleware** is very broad. Most of the time you will find it used in the context of distributed applications. In the context of web applications, the pattern is used by web frameworks to managing response and request objects.

I am not going to describe more detail what middleware is but here are a few other design patterns that can be useful. The patterns are not just like middleware but try to solve similar problems. Usually, there is not just one pattern to solve use cases as you have.

- [Chain of Responsibility](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/chain_of_responsibility_pattern.htm)
- [Intercepting Filter Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/intercepting_filter_pattern.htm)

I have seen that usually in code level, these patterns have similar features than in middleware. Maybe a good to check them if you can find more examples.

I am not sure about your use case and infrastructure but one problem that usually rises is the error handling between the steps.

Comment: This is a very insightful answer, thank you! I took a look at chain of responsibility, command and interceptor patterns. Very useful indeed!

Comment: Thanks. Here is still a few other choices to check out. One is State pattern that can be useful https://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern

Also, try to find examples from State Machine that can solve a similar problem in a different way. Not just like middleware but steps are more decoupled. 

Third suggest is to look some kind "background processing" library/framework that could handle basic workflow and if needed, keep state. If that kind implementation is applicable.

For simple usage, you probably don't need any framework anyway.

Comment: State machine has always been interesting to me, I will take a better look at it for this use case, thank you! This system is very decoupled system-wise, so lots of background/async things are happening, but this specific flow will need to be very sync, as it keeps changing its state in every state and needs to be ordered etc.